# How to increase the size of the root partition under drive 1 with free space under drive 2

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, gparted

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside windows, but I quickly got run out of space and the only available space is not under the same SSD. Is there a way to extend the root partition or should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: you can't extend the root partition to the second drive, but you can create a *new* partition to use in Ubuntu, and move whatever is taking up tons of space to there.

Comment: @Esther, Thanks for the fast response. I will consider your solution.

Comment: @Nmath, I did not know if this will work, as in my case, I have two different SSDs.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Nmath.

Comment: Search this site for logical volume and see if anything meets your needs.

Comment: You can create a new partition on HDD and move /home to it. Most of your data should be in /home. To see size of /home and then compare to size of / partition. `sudo du -sh /home` To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Or you can just move data keeping /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk